# font-size:8px appearance in edge/firefox/chrome not the same

Tags: css

I have a simple `a` with style `font-size:8px`, but the result in edge is different from chrome and firefox.
I also tried `font-size:50%`, the result is the same.

```
<a style="font-size:8px;display:block;text-align:center;color:#f8e8b8;background-color:#205010">
    雪亚小站旗下
</a>
```

Or you can just visit my website https://snowyyang.com/rfwiki/QandA

`font-size:8px` in edge
[image: edge]

`font-size:8px` in chrome and firefox
[image: firefox/chrome] <--

I want to keep the same appearance in all browsers without using images. What should I do?

Comment: to me everything is fine with chrome mac, I increased by px and decreased without problems

Comment: @Sergiu would you please directly visit my website https://snowyyang.com/rfwiki/QandA ?

Comment: on mac safari and chrome google use `font-size: 8px; `from the inspect I can easily increase it

Comment: I have tried your website on Windows 10 - Chrome, Edge, Firefox and even IE11 all give the same size characters. Are you sure your Edge hasn't got a minimum character size set or similar?

Comment: @AHaworth you're right. it's edge settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's turn out that the minimum font size in Edge is 12px.